# WSL 2 with ubuntu: x509 certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: x509certificate

I am using ubuntu in a wsl2 from my windows pc and with every download I want to make I get the error: x509 certificate signed by unknown authority.

Example: For installing kubernetes I follow the instructions:

```
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
```

leading to: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Does anybody know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check system time `date`, you can use `curl --insecure` flag

Comment: this did only solve the problem for a certain curl command , but not generally

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem only by downgrading to WSL1

Comment: Downgrading to WSL1 did not solve the problem for me.